# HDMI connection percieved as DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amdgpu

I'm using MacbookPro16,1 with AMD Radeon 5500 on kubuntu and amdgpu driver that comes with kubuntu-23.04-6.4.7-t2-lunar [from this github repo](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu/releases/tag/v6.4.7-1)

`dpkg -l xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` shows following

```
||/ Name                      Version      Architecture Description
+++-=========================-============-============-=======================================
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu 23.0.0-1     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

I'm trying to connect to an external display's HDMI port with a HDMI to HDMI cable and a HDMI to USB-C converter connected to one of my built-in USB-C port. The external display shows up in system setting of KDE connected, but the external display shows "no signal" message on screen.

After trying out nearly all methods on the internet with no change, I noticed that in my `xrandr -q` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4992 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 3072x1920+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 215mm
   3072x1920     60.00*+
   1920x1200     60.00
   1920x1080     60.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     60.00
   1280x1024     60.00
   1440x900      60.00
   1280x800      60.00
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.00
   640x480       60.00
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 connected 1920x1080+3072+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00*   59.94
   1680x1050     60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      60.00
   1280x800      60.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DisplayPort-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Instead of HDMI, it is shown as a DisplayPort device. I guess they are different in term of connection protocol? Could that be the reason why the external display have no signal? Is there a way to overide this to tell the GPU to connect it to a HDMI port instead?

Thank you very much